# Android updating wrong contacts

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I'm trying to make my app update some contacts but it's updating the wrong people. I get the contact Name, Number and Raw Id. Then if it is true to my if I change his number and update it by his Raw ID. That's my code:

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext())
{
    String numero;
    String fnum;
    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    int id = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID));
    String tipo = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(" ", "");
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("-", "");
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("+", "");
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("*", "");
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("#", "");

    int tamanho = phoneNumber.length();
    numero = phoneNumber;

    if (tamanho == 12) {
        if (checar.indexOf(numero.substring(1, 3) + ",") != -1) {
            if(numero.substring(3).startsWith("9")){
                fnum = numero.substring(0, 3) + "" + numero.substring(4);
                update(id, fnum, tipo);
            }
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
phones.close();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And that's the update method:

```
public void update(int id, String number, String tipo)
    {

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        // Number
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?"+ " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, tipo});
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number);
        ops.add(builder.build());

        // Update
        try
        {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what's wrong is that you're retrieving RAW_CONTACT_ID when you get the number, but in update() you're passing this value to the column CONTACT_ID. The first one points to raw contacts, but the second one points to the Contacts table. Don't mix them!

I also notice that you're trying to update the ORGANIZATION column with the value of Phone.TYPE, which may or may not work.

Comment: I got this method on the internet. I didn't want to update the ORGANIZATION column, can I just remove it? (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE  ===>  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.TYPE)